# Sphinx cannot index

Tags: sphinx

I know there is not for sphinx support. But you always answer very quickly, hope you excuse me.
my sphinx file look like:

#

## indexer settings

#

indexer
{
mem_limit = 32M
}

#

## searchd settings

#

searchd
{
listen            = 127.0.0.1
log               = /home/jackey/workspace/socrates/sphinx/log/searchd.log
query_log         = /home/jackey/workspace/socrates/sphinx/log/query.log
read_timeout      = 5
client_timeout    = 300
max_children      = 30
pid_file          = /home/jackey/workspace/socrates/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
max_matches       = 1000
seamless_rotate   = 1
preopen_indexes   = 0
unlink_old        = 1
mva_updates_pool  = 1M
max_packet_size   = 8M
max_filters       = 256
max_filter_values = 4096
}

#

## datasource: socrates_dev_local_node

#

source socrates_dev_local_node
{
type = mysql
sql_host = localhost
sql_user = root
sql_pass = admin
sql_db   = socrates_dev_local
sql_port =

sql_query_pre = \
  SET NAMES utf8
sql_query = \
  SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 0 AS searchlight_deleted \
FROM  \
node node \
WHERE (( (node.nid BETWEEN $start AND $end ) ))
sql_query_info = \
  SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 0 AS searchlight_deleted \
FROM  \
node node \
WHERE (( (node.nid = $id) ))
sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(nid), MAX(nid) FROM node WHERE nid > 0
sql_range_step = 1000
sql_ranged_throttle = 0

sql_attr_uint = searchlight_deleted 
sql_attr_uint = nid
}

#

## index: socrates_dev_local_node

#

index socrates_dev_local_node
{

## Index configuration

source = socrates_dev_local_node
  path = /home/jackey/workspace/socrates/sphinx/indexes/
  docinfo = extern
  mlock = 0
  morphology = stem_en
  charset_type = utf-8
  html_strip = 0
}

#

## datasource: socrates_dev_local_search_node

#

source socrates_dev_local_search_node
{
type = mysql
sql_host = localhost
sql_user = root
sql_pass = admin
sql_db   = socrates_dev_local
sql_port =

sql_query_pre = \
  SET NAMES utf8
sql_query = \
  SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.status AS node_status, node.created AS node_created, users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS users_uid, node.type AS node_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 0 AS searchlight_deleted \
FROM  \
node node \
INNER JOIN users users ON node.uid = users.uid \
WHERE (( (node.nid BETWEEN $start AND $end ) ))
sql_query_info = \
  SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.status AS node_status, node.created AS node_created, users.name AS users_name, users.uid AS users_uid, node.type AS node_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 0 AS searchlight_deleted \
FROM  \
node node \
INNER JOIN users users ON node.uid = users.uid \
WHERE (( (node.nid = $id) ))
sql_query_range = SELECT MIN(nid), MAX(nid) FROM node WHERE nid > 0
sql_range_step = 1000
sql_ranged_throttle = 0

sql_attr_uint = searchlight_deleted 
sql_attr_uint = node_status 
sql_attr_timestamp = node_created 
sql_attr_uint = users_uid 
sql_attr_str2ordinal = node_type 
sql_attr_uint = field_data_body_entity_id
}

#

## index: socrates_dev_local_search_node

#

index socrates_dev_local_search_node
{

## Index configuration

source = socrates_dev_local_search_node
  path = /home/jackey/workspace/socrates/sphinx/indexes/
  docinfo = extern
  mlock = 0
  morphology = stem_en
  charset_type = utf-8
  html_strip = 0
}

when use index command:
indexer --config socrates.conf
output like that:

Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/home/jackey/workspace/socrates/sphinx/sphinx.merged.conf'...
total 0 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 0 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
Indexing complete.

I am very sure it have many node in database.
I lose something ??

Comment: I don't see the error. what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no error. The indexer only tells you that it has indexed 0 domcuments, which means that your sql query doesn't output anything. Try it more simpler, whithout `$start` and `$end`